# UITextField placeholder alignment scrolling trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, constraints

I'm working on a registration form actually and i'm facing some kind of trouble.

I'm using an UITextField into my cell and I wrote a string into the placeholder. Everything runs fine until I try to center the UITextField.textAlignment. It, somehow, manages not to center it. I checked it up and did some test and I think it might be an issue du to Constraints (I really want my form to work for the iphone 4s, 5, 6 and 6+ screens). It looks almost centered when i'm on iphone 6 but then you see the string less and less centered, going for right side if you switch to iphone 5 then iphone 4s.. So far I only used both heights Constraints.

Now the "good" thing is when I scroll my tableView, if my cells get out of sight, once I reload my cells, the placeholder string appears a second time but in the right place (the real center this time) with the old missplaced placeholder string. I would like this placeholder showing when I scroll appears when I first load my table because it seems it is the exact result I want to get. But this only appears when I try to center the placeholder, if i don't, there is no second placeholder string showing. I'll give you 2 links for the pictures, since my english is terrible, you guys might be able to understand better this way.

+= Nothing is happening into my code when I scroll the tableView, it is running the same CellForRowAtIndexPath but still with different result.

Thank you for all advices and help you guys will bring to me

Normal screen with Placeholder not totally on center: 
[image]

Buggy screen with the second Placeholder on right position:
[image]

Here is my code running:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSString *identifier = @"id";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        self.LastName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        self.LastName.placeholder= @"Last Name";
        self.LastName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.LastName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.LastName.delegate = self;
        [self.LastName setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        [self.LastName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.LastName];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        self.Name = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        self.Name.placeholder= @"Name";
        self.Name.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.Name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.Name.delegate = self;
        [self.Name setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        [self.Name setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.Name];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        self.Email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        self.Email.placeholder= @"Email";
        self.Email.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.Email.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.Email.delegate = self;
        [self.Email setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        [self.Email setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.Email];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        self.Password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        self.Password.placeholder= @"Password";
        self.Password.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.Password.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.Password.delegate = self;
        [self.Password setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        [self.Password setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.Password];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 4)
    {
        self.RepetePassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        self.RepetePassword.placeholder= @"Repeat password";
        self.RepetePassword.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        self.RepetePassword.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.RepetePassword.delegate = self;
        [self.RepetePassword setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
        [self.RepetePassword setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.RepetePassword];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 5)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Register";
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
        [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];

    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:20.0f];
    [cell.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that you are allocating your uitextfield in cellForRowAtIndexPath method thats why they appears again and again when you are scrolling.Because nature of uitableview is do whatever developer want in visible cells not in the out of screen thats why when you scrolling this method calling again and again. Just try to allocate textfield in viewDidLoad method or somewhere else. 
The second thing is to make them visible as you wanted, you may just use constraints center horizantically and vertically in uitableviewcell. To do that in UI just select your uitextfield hold the control key and drag it in that then click center horizanticall and vertically.
I hope these advices can solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you, your first answer really helped me to understand my mistake. But i fail at understanding the second part, my uiTextField is only in my code, I did not make it into my storyboard so I guess i have to fix the constraints into the code ?

Comment: Absouletly you can do that in code and its better to do that in code than in ui. So just examine below code how to do that. I just gave 50 between bounds and you may fix that as you like.
yourtextfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; 
 NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourtextfield);
 NSArray *constarints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[yourtextfield]-50-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
 [yourtextfield addConstraints:constarints]; 

And do the same vertically if you need.

Comment: Thank you, after 2h of hard work, i figured out how to fix these constraints (got some troubles since it was a self.LastName and I was using constraits before putting my TextView into the Cell and i was constraining the TextView instead of the Cell itself). Thank you very much for the help, I learned a bit more about iOs today thanks to you.